# How can I hide a standard report from the print button pull down menu list on Odoo 8?

Tags: printing, report, odoo-8

I have replaced a report from the odoo stock module with my own version.

How can I hide the standard odoo report from the pull down menu list of the print button. I want to do it without deleting the standard report?

I have tried, unsuccessfully, to set the field menu for the stock report id inside a record tag.

I am wondering Where Odoo stores the `menu="False"` attribute of the report tag. Because the table `ir_act_report_xml` has no field `menu`.

Answer (score 9):

Just We need to override the ids for the base report of stock and you may try to do some things like this.

```xml
    <report 
        string="Picking" 
        id="stock.action_report_picking" 
        model="stock.picking" 
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        name="stock.report_picking" 
        file="stock.report_picking" 
        menu="False"
    />
```

I have update my existing ids of base stock Picking report in my custom module.

I hope this should helpful for you ..:)

Comment: This answer is correct, the `menu="False"` actually removes the report from the menu

Comment: Doesn't work for me in V8, and error is strange "ParseError: "ParseError: "The ID "purchase.report_purchase_quotation" refers to an uninstalled module". That's not correct. Purchase is installed as well as in dependency of the module. :(

Comment: @StackUP have u tried to check the same functionality with newly created demo or without demo ?

Comment: @DASADIYACHAITANYA: I tried in an old DB running on production for almost a year.

Comment: @StackUP Issue is with module upgradition process nothing else becuase I have already used from my end so many other report which totally fixed this issue. just try to fix and upgrade properly this will work in odoo V8,V9,V10 as well

Comment: Works to Odoo 11 too... i used this solution because the <delete id="model.report_id" model="ir.actions.report"/> doesn't work on Odoo 11.
Thanks